# google marker does not display a valid address in a loop, but work for single request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been facing a weird problem with google marker api,
i am fetching addresses from database, there are few address that do not work in a loop.
here is an example, http://admissiontimes.com/universityDb/welcome/universityProfile/Delhi_Institute_of_Pharmaceutical_Sciences_&_Research/557

this page clearly displays the marker for the address, but http://admissiontimes.com/universityDb/welcome/universityIn/India-Delhiuniversity/Delhi page has the problem,
it displays address for specific location. but if you would see the console with firebug(as i have logged addresses that re not displyed), the fist address in the console is exactly the same has the first link, but is not displayed,

what could have been the problem?

please help

thank you

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is you are going over the geocoder query limit (too many requests in a short time frame).

The workaround I have seen is to use `setTimeout` to delay successive requests.

Even better is to separately use the geocoder only once for each location (convert the human readable address to latitude and longitude coordinates), and store the LatLng result in your database, rather than use the geocoder every time your map webpage loads.

Comment: i do have the lat-lang saved, using them would resolve the problem?

Comment: What I mean is to avoid calling the geocoder so many times in a row. Based on my experience, it should be returning the Over Query Limit error status. So yes, use your saved lat lng directly to create your markers.